# Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. localhost Laravel Xampp Issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, server, xampp

Strange Error, most likely the solution is easy and axiomatic, I just couldn't come up with it, I had created a project in Laravel about 2 years ago and now I want to launch it back, so I installed Laravel, xampp, composer and all that it requires to start successfully, I also created the database according to the code as well. The project starts fine at first, the welcome page view works fine, but when i try to register to the system it doesn't work and it represents that error, it lets me fill the form but when i press on register it stops and returns me the following error:

```
 Object not found! 
    The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring 
      page seems to be wrong or outdated.
       
    Please inform the author of that page about the error. If you think 
          this is a server error, please contact the webmaster. Error 404 
     localhost 

   Apache/2.4.43 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.3.20
```

my RegisterController.php code:

```
   namespace App\Http\Controllers;

   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
   use App\User;
   use App\Ens;
   use App\Role;
  class RegisterController extends Controller
  {


 public function create() {

      return view('/register');

 }

public function store(Request $request) {
       
       $user = new User;
       $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
         $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
        if($request->hasFile('photo')){
                $user->photo= $request->photo->store('avatar');
              }

         if($request->hasFile('image')){
                $user->image= $request->image->store('avatar');
              }


         $user->save();

         $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'Elève')->first());

         auth()->login($user);

        return redirect('/');

          }
```

route web.php part of code:

```
     Route::get('/register', 'RegisterController@create');
     Route::post('/register', 'RegisterController@store');
```

So i'm guessing the problem could be the url inside the code or maybe in the browser itself, the path is different from when I first time created the website, I used to access the website using: 127.0.0.1:8000 in my browser..
now that url doesn't work at all, it takes long loading and  returns finally nothing so i'm accessing now using this following url: localhost/myproject/public and it works just fine

So is there anything I have to change in the code because of this recent URL (like add 'public' in the path)?? I will be grateful for any kind of help. Thank you!

Comment: Update your Queation title please, its non-english

Comment: @STA Done! Thanks for your remark.

Comment: If you have `Auth::routes()`?

Comment: @STA no I'm not using 'Auth::routes()' because I have multiple users in my system and each user has to register according to its role, so the RegisterController has more than just that code above.. any ideas?

Comment: Have you installed **laravel/ui**?

Comment: @STA well, I had a problem doing that via cmd directly from my project's folder so I installed that in a different project and then copied the files to my real project, and I still have the same error message **Object not found!**  whenever I try to register to my system

Comment: @STA the URL I want to go to, which returns this error is: **http://localhost/public/register** with no project name on it, is this strange?

Comment: On RegisterController Add this on `__construct ` method : `$this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['register']]);` hope this helps

Comment: @STA I tried it, still it doesn't come with a result :/

Answer (score 0):

I think your  problem is on return view. Remove forward slash in view function.

```
Return view('register')
```

Comment: I tried, and it didn't work still, the URL I want to go to for registration, the one that returns the above error is: localhost/public/register with no project name on it, is this strange? and how to fix it?